# How to make this output file both read and write mode from data grid view to .xls file? currently it produce read only file

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

**This is the office object for excel**

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
```

**Worksheet name and creation**

```
            app.Visible = false;
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
```

**for write data from gridview to excel file**

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewShowAllPassword.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i+1] = dataGridViewShowAllPassword.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewShowAllPassword.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridViewShowAllPassword.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j+1] = dataGridViewShowAllPassword.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

**Saving the file**

```
            workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\Users\Public\Desktop\output.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            app.Quit();
```

**Here is the image**
[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The posted code appears to save the Excel file successfully. Using the “xls” format gives a “warning” when opening the file, however it is still editable/save(able). I am confident the warning is coming from the “version” of Excel on my machine and the “xls” format. Again, it is not clear what you mean by _”currently it produce read only file”_ … the posted code produces a read/write(able) Excel file.

Comment: As I stated earlier, using your posted code... the Excel file opens without the read-only restriction. It may help to “close” the workbook before quitting the application. I would recommend trying different xl formats, using the second argument in the `SaveAs` call. I am using Excel 2016. The only other issue that you may have is that simply using the `app.quit()` is not necessarily “releasing” the application from the OS. It may quit; however, the process may still stick around until the OS decides to release the application.

Comment: You can check this by running the application several times, then check the “Task Manager.” My tests showed that there were numerous background “excel” process still running i.e. not released. That is why when you use “Interop` it is usually best to “release” the resource(s) after the workbook/application closes/quits. It may help to “release” the workbook, then release the app like: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);.` This should be done either way as without it the process may still remain in memory.

Comment: Yap. You are right. After releasing the app now there are no issue to have multiple excel process running. I use Office 2013 , if I use .xlsx there is issue to open it. But the read only mode still on the top.  But if I go to properties of that output.xlxs then there is no check mark on the read-only mode.